# Positioning, relocating the navigation menu on the website

Tags: html, css, web, navigationbar

I just started html5 and css
I'm trying to make a cv website. I have added a navigation bar, but I cannot move it where I want and can't size the bar.

[now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6J3B.png)

a wanna like this

[i wanna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig9I2.png)

HTML codes:

Duman

```
  <br /><br /><br />

 
  
  <div="menu">
  
  <ul>
      
      <li><a href="#egitim">Eğitim</a></li>
      <li><a href="#bilgisayar">Bilgisayar Bilgisi</a></li>
      <li><a href="#hobi">Hobileri</a></li>
      <li><a href="#deneyim">İş Deneyimi</a></li>
      <li><a href="#iletisim">İletişim</a></li>
  </ul>

  </div="menu">
```

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    
   <title>Duman</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stil.css">

  </head>

  <body>

      <br /><br /><br />
 
      <div="menu">
      
      <ul>
          
          <li><a href="#egitim">Eğitim</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bilgisayar">Bilgisayar Bilgisi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#hobi">Hobileri</a></li>
          <li><a href="#deneyim">İş Deneyimi</a></li>
          <li><a href="#iletisim">İletişim</a></li>
      </ul>

      </div="menu">

      


 </body>

</html>

Comment: Post your code in the question

Comment: I cannot add my css codes, it gives an error

Comment: Hi Volkan welcome to Stack Overflow we are happy to see you. If you tried any answer and it did solve your problem feel free to give up vote and mark as real answer also please try to use search in here before opening new subject. Personally I will suggest you to use Bootstrap layouts. You can also use float="right" as plain CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of flex for divs to partition your page.
I have created a demo for above expected image. Inside menu you can replace it with your CSS and it should work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         body {background-color: powderblue;}
         h1   {color: blue;}
         p    {color: red;}
         .main-container {
         width: 100%;
         background: yellow;
         display: flex;
         }
         .left-container{
         display: flex;
         width: 30%;
         }
         .right-container{
         display: flex;
         width: 70%;
         }
         .photo {
         margin: 2em;
         background: blue;
         width: 10em;
         height: 10em;
         }
         .menu {
         display: flex;
         }
         ul {
         list-style-type: none;
         margin: 3em;
         padding: 0;
         display: flex;
         }
         li {
         margin: 0 .5em;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="main-container">
      <div class="left-container">
         <div class="photo">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-container">
         <div="menu">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#egitim">Eğitim</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bilgisayar">Bilgisayar Bilgisi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#hobi">Hobileri</a></li>
            <li><a href="#deneyim">İş Deneyimi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#iletisim">İletişim</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      </div="menu">
      <div>
   </body>
</html>
```